# Error reading geojson features in OpenLayers 4.6

Tags: openlayers, geojson

So, I'm starting to build a simple OpenLayers 4.6 application and I'm trying to make a simple map with some point features. I was trying to modify the [GeoJSON](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html?q=geojson) example on the OpenLayers site. The issue that I'm running into is that something is wrong with my geojson object and application is throwing the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Technically, since this is an object and not an array, it shouldn't have a length property, so I don't really know why it's throwing the error. The main difference seems to be that I have added "properties" attributes to the features in the geojson object.

```
var geojsonObject = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name": "EPSG:3857"},
    "Features":[
      {
      "type" : "feature",
      "geometry" : {"type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [-4.65, 79.36]},
      "properties" : {
      "name" : "ARED",
      "country" : "Rwanda",
      "sector" : "ITC"
     }
    },{
    "type" : "feature",
    "geometry" : {'type':'Point','coordinates': [8.08, 29.19]},
    "properties" : {
      "name" : "Bio Phyto Collines",
      "country": "Benin", 
      "sector": "Organic Ag Inputs"
      }  
    }
  ]}}
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});
```

The error gets thrown on the readFeatures method when passed the geojson. I'm open to other implementations, but I was trying to something more elegant than creating each feature manually.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `geojsonObject` Object again. and please indent better with JSON type Object. I added comments on the wrong points in the code

```
var geojsonObject = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": { // First, you didn't close `crs` brackets
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:3857"
    }
  },
  "features":[{
    "type" : "Feature", // Second, it's `Feature' not `feature`
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "Point", 
      "coordinates" : [-4.65, 79.36]
    },
    "properties" : {
      "name" : "ARED",
      "country" : "Rwanda",
      "sector" : "ITC"
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "Feature", // Feature again.
    "geometry" : {
      'type':'Point',
      'coordinates': [8.08, 29.19]
    },
    "properties" : {
      "name" : "Bio Phyto Collines",
      "country": "Benin", 
      "sector": "Organic Ag Inputs"
    }  
  }]
};
```

Comment: I realize it’s choking on the json, but “feature” is correct for a single feature object, features is the array

Comment: Oh, it's mis-typo. actually it's `Feature` not `Features` and `feature`